# How can I force the Typescript compiler to emit a define call when it compiles with --outFile?

Tags: typescript

I need all of the `.js` files emitted by the TypeScript compiler to include an AMD-style call to the `define` function. It seems like this should be a thing TypeScript can do, but I can't figure out how to get it to do it all of the time.

Right now, the emitted Javascript will contain the AMD define call so long as the .ts file has a dependency (`import`/`require`) or produces one (`export`).  However, for my project it is possible for a valid script file to neither have a dependency nor to produce one.

The missing `define` call is a problem because I use the `--outFile` compiler switch to generate a single javascript file with all the AMD modules named, and this one file/module executes immediately instead of waiting to be potentially used in a `require` statement like the other AMD modules at this level.

Examples follow:

*module_a.ts* with silly, but illustrative destructive content if it runs unexpectedly

```
const el = document.getElementById("app");
el.innerHTML = "";
```

When compliled with TypeScript 2.9.2, using the following switches: `tsc --target es5 --module amd --outFile application.js module_a.ts` produces the following:

*application.js*

```
var el = document.getElementById("app");
el.innerHTML = "";
```

However, this version of *module_a.ts* will render what I'm looking for:

*module_a.ts*

```
export const el = document.getElementById("app");
el.innerHTML = "";
```

*application.js* the first line of this module is what I want to see regardless of whether I use `import`/`require`/`export`

```
define("module_a", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.el = document.getElementById("app");
    exports.el.innerHTML = "";
});
```

If I can't find a way to force the compiler to emit the define, then I'll be back (with a new question) to figure out my next task to write a TSLint rule to detect this situation, so that I will know I need to add a fake `export` to the TS module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) says that having `import` or `export` at top level is the only way  for the compiler to determine if the file is a module or a part of global script:

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a
>   top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file
>   without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a
>   script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore
>   to modules as well).

As you mention in your question, `define` appears in the output only if the compiled file is a module.

So, adding fake top-level `export` or `import` is the only solution. The way to do that without any effects at runtime (without actually importing or exporting anything from AMD module) is to import some type defined in some of your other modules:

```
import {SomeType} from './some-module';
```

If `SomeType` is never used at runtime, the compiler will not emit `import` or `require` in javascript, but still will compile the file as a module and add `define` function for AMD.

If your `target` and `module` options were `ESNext`, there is a newer and arguably better way to get the same result - just add this statement somewhere to turn the file into a module:

```
import.meta;
```

I don't think there is a tslint rule that requires every file to be a module. I don't know how hard it is to implement such a rule - if tslint rules have easy access to TypeScript AST, then the rule could check [this property which is non-null](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/types.ts#L2556) for `SourceFile` if it's a module:

```
    /**
     * The first "most obvious" node that makes a file an external module.
     * This is intended to be the first top-level import/export,
     * but could be arbitrarily nested (e.g. `import.meta`).
     */
    /* @internal */ externalModuleIndicator: Node;
```